# Workaround for SubWCRev 1.7 with svn:externals

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn

My build script uses [SubWCRev](http://tortoisesvn.net/docs/release/TortoiseSVN_en/tsvn-subwcrev.html) to embed an svn revision number and my repository contains an [`svn:externals` definition](http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.7/svn.advanced.externals.html) to share a header file between two projects.

My Jenkins build server does not authenticate with the svn server in the same way as developers, and so uses a different repository URL.

Since updating the build server to TortoiseSVN 1.7, the build script is failing with the following errors:

> SubWCRev : E155032: The node '[shared.h]' comes from unexpected repository
>   'http://[developer]', expected 'http://[build server]'; if this node is a file external
>   using the correct URL in the external definition can fix the problem,
>   see [issue #4087](http://subversion.tigris.org/issues/show_bug.cgi?id=4087)
>
> SubWCRev : E200033: cannot rollback savepoint - SQL
>   statements in progress, executing statement 'ROLLBACK TO s390'
>
> SubWCRev : E200034: SQLite busy at transaction rollback; resetting all
>   busy SQLite statements to allow rollback
>
> Build step 'Execute Windows batch command' marked build as failure

where E155032 quotes the `svn:externals` definition.

I am not passing the `-e` switch to SubWCRev so externals should be ignored.

My current options are to either roll back to TortoiseSVN 1.6 or change the build server authentication to make the repository URL match.

**Is there a better workaround?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use relative path in externals definition instead of absolute